# Programmatically created form is blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm trying to create a pop up to notify users of a successful action. It is supposed to be visible for a couple seconds and fade away on its own. To do this, I've created a form that inherits from Form and sets the ShowWithoutActivation property to true, as well as a static class to control its construction and manipulate its opacity.

The problem is that when the new form is created, it has the correct size and initial opacity, but is completely blank. The only child control, a docked (Fill)  label does not show. The Background/Foreground Color properties I set in the designer seem to be ignored in favor of default values as well. The Form fades and closes as intended.

The form itself:

```
public partial class TempForm : Form
{
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public TempForm(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        messageLabel.Text = message;
    }

    private TempForm() { }

}
```

The static class that creates it:

```
public static class FadeAwayNotifier
{

    public static void DisplayFadeNotification(Point parentLocation, string message)
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            int fadeDelay = 2000;
            int animationLength = 1000;
            int threadRestLength = 20;

            Form popUp = buildForm(parentLocation, message);
            popUp.Show();

            int opacityIncrements = (animationLength / threadRestLength);
            double opacityDecrementAmount = popUp.Opacity / opacityIncrements;

            Thread.Sleep(fadeDelay);

            for (int i = 0; i < opacityIncrements; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(threadRestLength);
                popUp.Opacity -= opacityDecrementAmount;
            }

            popUp.Close();
        });

    }

    private static Form buildForm(Point startLocation, string text)
    {
        TempForm returnForm = new TempForm(text);

        returnForm.Location = startLocation;
        returnForm.messageLabel.Text = text;
        returnForm.BackColor = Color.Black;
        returnForm.ForeColor = Color.White;

        return returnForm;
    }

}
```

And, if it's helpful, here is the designer code for TempForm:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.messageLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // messageLabel
        // 
        this.messageLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.messageLabel.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.messageLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Cambria", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.messageLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.messageLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.messageLabel.Name = "messageLabel";
        this.messageLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(254, 81);
        this.messageLabel.TabIndex = 0;
        this.messageLabel.Text = "Message";
        this.messageLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // TempForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 19F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(254, 81);
        this.Controls.Add(this.messageLabel);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Cambria", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        this.Name = "TempForm";
        this.Opacity = 0.8D;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Text = "tempForm";
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    public System.Windows.Forms.Label messageLabel;
```

For those asking how the method is being called:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        /* Input validation here */

        if (cmbBox.SelectedValue != null)
        {
             updateMethod(a, b....out errorMessage);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
                       FadeAwayNotifier.DisplayFadeNotification(this.Location, "Rule successfully updated");

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("A selection must be made in order to update");

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

I've searched around but haven't seen anything that seemed to relate to the situation. I'm happy to be corrected if I missed something, though.

Why is the form that's created completely blank?

Comment: you dont show the code that puts the control(s) on the form

Comment: you really shouldn't create a form in a task.

Comment: I recommend using UWP https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Toast-notifications-in-17c55610

Comment: @pm100 The code that puts the label on the form was done through the designer. Would the designer code still be useful?

Comment: @Danial A. White Can you expound as to why creating a form in a task should not be done? I was trying to do this asynchronously so as not to interrupt the user's work.

Comment: @Tony I would love to use UWP, but this is being appended to a legacy project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is blank because you are trying to show it inside `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

`Task.Factory.StartNew()` runs code inside it asynchronous which is for some reason problem for `form.Show()` method.

Solution for this is to instead of `Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(...` use `Task t = new Tast(....` and then after you created task you run it with `t.RunSynchronously()`. This way it will work.

How i am displaying temp forms is:

Create temporary form create new blank winform (through vs solution explorer)

Add code like this:

```
public partial class TempForm : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    double seconds = 3;

    public TempForm(int secs, string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Custom property to dock it to down right to the screen
        Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
        this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width, workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);

        t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        this.seconds = (secs != 0) ? secs : this.seconds;
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }

    private void TempForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = (int)(seconds * 1000);
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(CloseForm);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void CloseForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public static void Show(int seconds, string text)
    {
        TempForm tf = new TempForm(seconds, text);
        tf.Show();
    }
}
```

To call it just use `TempForm.Show(10, "SomeText");`

Also make it look better (not like standard form) so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: While this code does work well and could be altered to my purposes I would still like to know the reason why my original solution was displaying a blank form.

Comment: Could you put your line where you call `DisplayFadeNotification` method?

Comment: @NealDarley Found out the solution why it happening and explanation. I will edit answer in 5 min

Comment: unfortunately, changing the task to run synchronously did not fix the issue. I'll continue tinkering with it.

Comment: @NealDarley are you sure since i have copy/paste whole your code, got same error and done this and it worked

Comment: I changed the code as you described, e.g. `Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` to `Task t = new Task(...).....t.RunAsynchronously` but nothing happened. Interestingly enough, I found that It was still starting out blank with your code in certain situations when it was being called. Also, when I removed the code to adjust the Opacity on the same thread using Thread.Rest(), it worked great. 

I suspect that the thread was resting so it could not complete drawing the controls before it needed to rest again. I will still mark your answer, as it helped. I would upvote if I could.